# How to convert numpy array to a tensor in this case?

Tags: arrays, numpy, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory

I have used this code previously, and it worked fine, but I am trying to differentiate between two variables, male & female in this case. I have a .csv file of names that generally correspond to females and males. I am trying to run this model, but it is not able to convert the array to a to a tensor in this case. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
    import tensorflow as tf #using keras nueral network 
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape= 
   (x_train.shape[1],), activation='sigmoid'))  
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape=x_train.shape, 
    activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) 
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', 
    metrics=['accuracy']) 
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10) #this is where the model goes wrong
```

Comment: post the full error from the model

Comment: ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float). I have posted the error.

Comment: Most of the time this fixes it. You can try it out: np.asarray(x_train).astype('float32')

Comment: Why do you have two Dense layers with `input_shape` parameter? There should just be one with that - the first layer. You can also make tensors from arrays using `tf.constant(x)`, where `x` is the array. You also have multiple layers with `sigmoid`. For the most part, it should just be the final layer.

Comment: I don't see a full error; full error is many lines with traceback!.  But the error in the comment means that the array is object dtype.  Check it's shape and dtype.  It should be multidimensional numeric dtype.  Most likely your starting array contains arrays or lists that vary in shape.  Didn't you get a "ragged array" warning?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `numpy` array into tensor using `tf.convert_to_tensor()`.

**For example:**

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,5,])
type(a)
```

Output:

```
numpy.ndarray
```

Converting `numpy` array to `tensor`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
b=tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
type(b)
```

Output:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor
```